# Rotary lever turns over with each cycle

Tags: animation

This is just the rod or whatever that goes on a steam train. Every turn it turns around for a few frames, then it goes back. There is nothing esoteric about the file!

PS: It's 2.69, but these basic things are probably the same on the current version!

[image]

[image]

Comment: C'mon guys- somebody must know why the levers switch direction once a rotation.

Comment: Hi, @anon, there are quite a few folks here who 'know how to use' Blender.. though it's true, none of us ever stops learning :).   Perhaps you could clarify your question a bit. Do you want the rods to stick out in one direction relative to the  locomotive, as if to a carriage, or do you want a rod to be a linkage between a pair of wheels, connecting 1 point on each, as they turn?

Comment: on a steam engine the bar stays within the 3 wheels. this one, once a cycle flys out as you see. run the blend file and it is obvious what it is doing wrong. thanks

Comment: Is this question REALLY beyond this forums members?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way of rigging it:

- A root cube-shaped Empty, here called 'Loco' is constrained to follow the 'Track' curve.
- The front, mid, and rear wheel-pairs are all parented to 'Loco'
- The front wheel has an Empty parented to it, at the appropriate offset: 'Couple Parent'

[image]

- Parented at the same offset to the mid-wheels, there's another Empty: 'Couple Target'
- The linking-rod is parented to 'Couple Parent', and given a *Locked Track* constraint, aiming it at 'Couple Target'. It's *Mirrored* across to the other side.

There are more parts here than are strictly necessary. (You could have used, for example, a 'Child Of' constraint on the linking-rod, with selected inheritance of transforms). But I think maybe this is easier to read, maintain and adjust.

The rotation of the wheels, in this version, is driven by the 'Evaluation Time' on the animated track. I haven't done the math to make the rotations correspond exactly to the distance travelled, but it looks OK.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks good. will it go up and down hills and follow a curve around bends? please post the file and i will see if it works in my version. Thanks very much

Comment: Hi, @anon125.. the link was there already, but I've updated it  this am for a better view through the camera..  (link at bottom of post).

Comment: sadly it wont run in 2.69. i mentioned the version i used in the original post. thanks for trying. it is the only version i will use

Comment: It turns out to be very tricky for me to run 269.. the **method** should still work, though. Nothing peculiar to later versions, I don't think.  I had to snap- realign your geometry  .. it was slightly out. The only thing I haven't mentioned in the post is _Copy Rotation_  around the axle, from the front wheels to the others. Set the whole thing up at the origin..  (forget the track for a while) introduce one constraint at a time, and ensure it works for all orientations of the 'Loco' parent empty.

Comment: wont even open the file!

Comment: Im hoping you can follow the method in your own file..

Comment: it does not sound like 2.69 rules. thanks